# Android - My Simple ListView/Toast app crashes on startup... any ideas?

Tags: android, listview, crash, toast, listview-adapter

I am creating a simple ListView app to learn more about programming for android.

However, this simple code (which is showing no errors whatsoever in Eclipse) is simply crashing on startup in the emulator. Any ideas?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static final String[] FRUITS = { "Apple", "Avocado", "Banana",
    "Blueberry", "Coconut", "Durian", "Guava", "Kiwifruit",
    "Jackfruit", "Mango", "Olive", "Pear", "Sugar-apple" };

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_fruit);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_fruit, FRUITS);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.list_fruit);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);



    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

}
```

list_fruit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:padding="10dp"
     android:textSize="20sp" >
</TextView>
```

Tried to find the stacktrace following your instructions, the only message that ame up was FATAL EXCEPTION: main.

Comment: Something in the logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_fruit, FRUITS);
```

to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FRUITS);
```

You have

```
setContentView(R.layout.list_fruit); // list_fruit.xml
```

and you use the same in the `ArrayAdapter`

Also change

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.list_fruit);
```

to

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

Also change to

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),FRUITS[postion], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Edit: `list_fruit.xml` does not have a ListView.

You need the below in `list_fruit.xml`

```
<ListView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listview"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then in `onCreate`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.list_fruit);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FRUITS);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),FRUITS[postion], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
}
```

Comment: @user3368408 post the full stack trace

Comment: @user3368408 if you need more help then you really need to post the stacktrace, and eventually also the layout file

Comment: Im new to this guys, so please bear with me.

What is the stacktrace, and how am I getting this to you guys?

Comment: @user3368408 in Eclipse goto Widnows open perspective open ddms and check the logcat extract the exception part and post it here by editing your question. also  post `list_fruit.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
 ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.list_fruit);
```

is wrong for sure, because you need to look up `id` with findViewById, so for example like this, but you need to be sure about having a listview element with that id then:

```
 ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_your_view);
```

Comment: someone thinks it is a good idea to do `findViewById(R.layout.list_fruit);` or what?

Answer (score 0):

For instance, this is wrong:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.list_fruit);
```

it should be something like:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list_fruit);
```

where my_list_fruit is just the android:id tag assigned in the xml:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/my_list_fruit"
.../>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using android simple_list_view_1

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static final String[] FRUITS = { "Apple", "Avocado", "Banana",
"Blueberry", "Coconut", "Durian", "Guava", "Kiwifruit",
"Jackfruit", "Mango", "Olive", "Pear", "Sugar-apple" };

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.list_fruit);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_fruit);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FRUITS);


listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);



listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

}

}

OR define a list_item.xml with textview in it ex:

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static final String[] FRUITS = { "Apple", "Avocado", "Banana", "Blueberry",
        "Coconut", "Durian", "Guava", "Kiwifruit", "Jackfruit", "Mango",
        "Olive", "Pear", "Sugar-apple" };
private ListView listView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_fruit);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_fruit);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.list_item, R.id.textView1, FRUITS);

    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                         listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}}
```

list_fruit.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_fruit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Both cases toast will fail

Comment: not it won't see this `((TextView) view).getText()` casting view to textview. `list_item.xml` the root element is LinearLayout

Comment: the first will probably work http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml?av=f but not the second